# jqTouch and animations

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

Anyone else ever had trouble with jqTouch and not being able to use all the animations? My project only seems to work using Flip to switch between the pages (well Divs actually).

Comment: If you're testing on a iPhone device, that should work. One big part is the `jqtouch.css` file. Can you provide some testable example?

Comment: I have an app where the basic slide is not working anymore. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

jQTouch is pretty picky so for both Scott and awendt I suggest you check you HTML. Make sure it's structured the way you see it on the jQtouch examples. If you're enclosing DIVs which are buttons in other DIV's or enclosing DIVs which are buttons inside of other elements, that will bring trouble.

For me it was always this that caused trouble with animations. I had animations with glitches and stuff like that.